# Align background image counting pixels from the center?

Tags: css

I realized the only way to get a background image properly aligned was counting pixels from the center, since using % and counting pixels from the left sometimes overlays images depending the screen size.

There must be a way to align it properly.

Is there a way to align the background image horizontally counting pixels from the center?

Thanks

Comment: did you try background-position:center top;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS I would use something like this.

```
div.background{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

The margin-left would be exactly half of the width of the background.

Comment: I have more than one background image, background: url(/Imagenes/tipbusca.png) 10px 400px no-repeat,  url(/Imagenes/tippublica.png) 96% 200px no-repeat #E2E4E9;

How can I add those attributes to both of them? Thanks

Comment: How do I add the margin to just the image? Since I'm inside .body it adds the margin to the whole body

Answer (score 1):

```
background-position:center top;
```